# How to use chartjs-plugin-zoom in laravel

Tags: laravel, chart.js, chartjs-plugin-zoom

I am trying to use the functionality of [chartjs-plugin-zoom](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-zoom/latest/) in my laravel application but I cant't get it to work.

In the blade I am loading the plugin through Cloudflare cdnjs:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.min.js" integrity="some-long-string" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-zoom/2.0.1/chartjs-plugin-zoom.min.js" integrity="some-other-long-string" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Then in the controller I create some chart to feed it to the view, setting some plugin specific options:

```php
$chart = new ReadOutChart();
// Fill chart with data
$chart->options([
    'plugins' => '{zoom: {zoom: { wheel: {enabled: true, mode: \'xy\'}}}}'
]);
```

where `ReadOutChart` is a chart building on the `ConsoleTVs\Charts\Classes\Chartjs\Chart` class.

Then again in the blade I plot the chart with:

```html
<div>
    {!! $chart->container() !!}
</div>
{!! $chart->script() !!}
```

The chart is shown correctly, but non of the plugin functionality seems to work.
I had a hard time getting to this point since I could not find a lot of documentation about using ChartJS plugins in laravel.
The most helpful info I could find was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55923003/how-to-use-plugins-in-chartjs-and-laravel-chart-consoletvs-chartsjs).

Do you spot a mistake or know how to get it working?

Additional info:

- laravel version: 10.16.1
- consoletvs/charts version: 6.6.0

Comment: Which version of chartjs? Which version of the plugin? No errors/warnings in your browser console?

Comment: @brombeer Oh you are right there is an message in the console, I did not think of checking that, it says: 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'helpers')
    at chartjs-plugin-zoom.min.js:7:337
    at chartjs-plugin-zoom.min.js:7:346

For the versions, the plugin version is 2.0.1, for chartjs it is coming from the laravel package consoletvs/charts not sure how to extract the chartjs version they use (`npm list -g chart.js` returns empty).

Comment: @brombeer the console seems to indicate Chart.js 3.9.1 when I look under Sources>Page

Comment: Apparently I was loading the ChartJS through Cloudflare cdnjs below the plugin in the blade. Because of my own absentmindedness and inexperience I had put it somewhere in the layout component below everything else ages ago. Thank you @brombeer to ask the right questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to inexperience, bad code design and absentmindedness I was loading ChartJS below the plugin. Moving the line before the loading of the plugin solved the issue:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.1/chart.js" integrity="..." crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.min.js" integrity="..." crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-zoom/2.0.1/chartjs-plugin-zoom.min.js" integrity="..." crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```